# How to model an event and time series generation with unequal length

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a dataset containing multiple time series with two features a time and a corresponding event. The time series are of unequal length. Im filling the shorter ones with values that indicate the end of the series and are never used anywhere else during the series, I am however not sure if this is the best approach.

My data basically is looking likes this:

```
[[[ -1.00, Event <],
  [  0.00, Event A],
  [  6.19, Event B],
  [ 55.41, Event C],
  [ 66.68, Event B],
  ...
  [293.54, Event G],
  [300.99, Event H],
  [ -0.50, Event >],
  [ -0.50, Event >],
  [ -0.50, Event >],
  [ -0.50, Event >]]]
```

And the shape would be

```
(1459,76,2)
```

The goal is to generate time series that look similar to the ones in my dataset, containing both features.

I am struggling to find a suitable approach to the problem as I am fairly new to the topic of neural-networks. I worked myself through a lot of related tutorials and searched for similar problems but at this point I am a bit lost and would appreciate and kind of help.

Comment: Yes, padding is the usual approach for this. TensorFlow provides a number of features to support this, such as [`tf.sequence_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask), [`tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) or the `sequence_length` parameter in [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) / [`tf.nn.static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn).

Comment: More recently [ragged tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors) have been introduced too, although they have more limited features and are not (at least for now) typically used for this.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these and try to work with them, sequence_mask seems pretty promising, any more recommendations, maybe a link to an example for a similar problem that I could use as a guide or something

Comment: Well if you just Google something like [tensorflow variable sequence length](https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorflow+variable+sequence+length) for example you should find several Q/A, tutorials and other resources that may be helpful. The exact solution depends a bit on what exactly you want to do with your data and how.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is to generate a time series like the one you have, I would model the problem of generating a (possibly valid) sequence of **actions** as a language generation problem. We first learn the language model of the actions from the train data set which will possibility learn the valid combinations of the actions. Once the language model is trained we can generate a random sequence of (possibly valid) actions.

### Example

My actions are say numbers (represented as strings) and valid combination of these are multiples (multiplication tables). Give such multiples I want to generated a random sequence of numbers

```
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline
from nltk.lm import MLE,Laplace
from nltk.lm import Vocabulary

# Generate Data
event = []
for i in range(1,100):
    event.append(["{0}".format(n*i) for n in range(10)])

# Train model 
train_data, padded_vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(3, event)
model = MLE(3)
model.fit(train_data, padded_vocab)

# Generate a random sequence of 10 numbers
model.generate(10)
```

Note: Ignore  `</s>` and `<s>` in generated sequence as they represent start and end of the sequence.

You might not be able to use the same approach to generate the timestaps (freature 1) because the vocabulary will be huge in that case.

Comment: I also thought about it as some sort of language generation problem but as you said that would be problematic for feature 1.

Comment: I am not sure how well the sequences will look if I generate the both features separately and just stick them together afterwards.

Comment: @Mendrus if feature 1 and feature 2 are independent, then it is perfectly OK to train two different models and stick the results together.